# Why @Formula returns null value

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, entity

I have this code. I have to make a unique field number with auto increment. This code gives me nothing. When I tried to make a persist in debug it gives me `null` value into `number` field. I tried to execute this in database query tool, all working fine. What's wrong?

My target entity:

```java
@Entity
@Table(schema = "public")
public class Policeman implements Serializable {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Long id;

   @Column
   @Formula(value = "(select max(student_id) from student)")//+1
   private Long number;

   @Column
   private String fam;

   @Column
   private String name;

   @Column
   private String otch;
}
```

Student entity:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="student", schema = "public")
public class Student extends Human implements Serializable {

   @Id
   @Column(name="student_id")
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
   private Long id;

   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.DETACH})
   @JoinColumn(name="fk_groups")
   private Group gruppa;
}
```

I omitted setters, getters and constructors.

Comment: `I have to make a unique field number with autoincrement.` Why you can not use db sequence for it? (As I see you try to do it for the `Student` entity) What database do you use?

Comment: I use postgres. i need to make all in project, not in db and not using "number" as id field

Answer (score -1):

It looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Technically, you can correct your declaration in the following way:

```java
@Entity
@Table(schema = "public")
public class Policeman implements Serializable {
   // ...

   // Please pay attention that you should not use @Column annotation here.
   @Formula(value = "(select max(public.student.student_id) from public.student)")
   private Long number;

   // ...
}
```

and it will return that you expect.

But, you should not use it for the mentioned in your question purpose:

> I have to make a unique field number with auto increment.

The typical `@Formula` usage is embedding into an entity the data calculated based on the other columns of the entity with usage of database specific functions. And you should take in mind that using `select` statement in `@Formula` can lead to the significant performance degradation.